# JACOB Create object using file location rather than ProgramID

Tags: java, activex, autoit, jacob

I'm trying to use JACOB to access the AutoitX library, however I would like to load the library via file locatio rather than through the registry. Is it possible to do this in JACOB?

This is the code I have:

```
ActiveXComponent autoitX = new ActiveXComponent("AutoitX.Control");
```

But I want something like this instead:

```
ActiveXComponent autoitX = new ActiveXComponent(Files.getParentFolder() + "/libs/AutoitX3.dll");
```

If it's not possible to reference the ActiveX component to load by file location then is it possible to create the registry values at run time instead?